# Customizing the size of the hover box for text in Bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, hover, bokeh

I’m knew to Python and Bokeh, so I apologize if this is an obvious question. I looked around, but didn’t see a similar question. I’ve made a figure using Python 3.6.4 and Bokeh 0.12.15 - it has circle glyphs and when you hover over a circle, you see some tooltip based text. Some text is longer than others, and this results in some of the hover boxes being really long, especially as you move towards towards the center of the figure. I need to include the given text, but want to standardize the hover box size to keep the width the same for every circle but adapt the height to accommodate longer text for some entries.

Is there a way to set the width of the hover box so it’s the same for every entry?

Thanks!

Comment: You can provide custom HTML/CSS for the tooltip: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#custom-tooltip

Comment: Thank you!  I was hoping for a simple way to restrict the width in bokeh - I went ahead and remade it with HTML.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As bigreddot mentioned, you can customize in bokeh:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#custom-tooltip

Using a div style for width will allow you to limit the width and force the text to wrap accordingly.